# Checking if a command is a built-in in ksh

Tags: scripting, ksh, function, shell-builtin

How can I check if a command is a built-in command for `ksh`?

In `tcsh` you can use `where`; in `zsh` and `bash` you can use `type -a`; and in some *modern* versions of `ksh` you can use `whence -av`.

What I want to do is write an `isbuiltin` function that works in any version of `ksh` (including `ksh88` and any other "old" versions of `ksh`) that behaves like this:

1. Accept multiple arguments and check if each is built-in
2. Return `0` (success) if all of the given commands are built-in
3. At the first non-built-in command, stop checking, return `1` (failure), and print a message to stderr.

I already have working functions like this for `zsh` and `bash` using the aforementioned commands.

Here is what I have for `ksh`:

```
isbuiltin() {
  if [[ "$#" -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: isbuiltin cmd" >&2
    return 1
  fi
  for cmd in "$@"
  do
    if [[ $cmd = "builtin" ]]; then
      #Handle the case of `builtin builtin`
      echo "$cmd is not a built-in" >&2
      return 1
    fi
    if ! whence -a "$cmd" 2> /dev/null | grep 'builtin' > /dev/null ; then
      echo "$cmd is not a built-in" >&2
      return 1
    fi
  done
}
```

This function works for ksh93.  However, it appears that ksh88's version of `whence` doesn't support the `-a` option, which is the option to make it display all occurrences.  Without the ability to display all occurrences, I can only use `whence -v`, which *does* tell me whether a command is built-in but only if there isn't also an alias or function of the same name.

**Question:** Is there something else I can use in place of `whence -av` in `ksh88`?

---

### Solution

Using the accepted answer (opening a subshell), here is my updated solution.  Place the following in .kshrc:

```
isbuiltin() {
  if [[ "$#" -eq 0 ]]; then
    printf "Usage: isbuiltin cmd\n" >&2
    return 1
  fi
  for cmd in "$@"
  do
    if (
         #Open a subshell so that aliases and functions can be safely removed,
         #  allowing `whence -v` to see the built-in command if there is one.
         unalias "$cmd";
         if [[ "$cmd" != '.' ]] && typeset -f | egrep "^(function *$cmd|$cmd\(\))" > /dev/null 2>&1
         then
           #Remove the function iff it exists.
           #Since `unset` is a special built-in, the subshell dies if it fails
           unset -f "$cmd";
         fi
         PATH='/no';
         #NOTE: we can't use `whence -a` because it's not supported in older versions of ksh
         whence -v "$cmd" 2>&1
       ) 2> /dev/null | grep -v 'not found' | grep 'builtin' > /dev/null 2>&1
    then
      #No-op.  Needed to support some old versions of ksh
      :
    else
      printf "$cmd is not a built-in\n" >&2
      return 1
    fi
  done
  return 0
}
```

I have tested this with ksh88 in Solaris, AIX, and HP-UX.  It works in all the cases I tested.  I have also tested this with the modern versions of ksh in FreeBSD, Ubuntu, Fedora, and Debian.

Comment: Note that if PATH is set to the empty  string, it searches for executable in the current directory. So if you have a "mybuiltin" executable file in the current directory, that `builtin mybuiltin` will return true. Set it to `PATH=/no` instead. You shouldn't use `echo` for arbitrary data. Use `printf "%s\n"` or `print -r --` instead.

Comment: Also note that `unset` being a _special_ builtin, if it fails, that exits the subshell. Your `builtin` would say that `.` is not a builtin for instance.

Comment: `which` doesn't work in ksh?

Comment: @wallyk `which` is not a built-in command in `ksh`, which means that it has no way of knowing whether another command is a built-in belonging to `ksh`.

Comment: @wallyk and even if it was built-in, it would still have the problem where aliases and functions would hide the built-in versions of the commands you're checking.

Comment: You are not supposed to answer your own question in the question itself, please post the answer part as a separate answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your concern is about aliases, just do:

```
[[ $(unalias -- "$cmd"; type -- "$cmd") = *builtin ]]
```

(`$(...)` create a subshell environment, so `unalias` is only in effect there).

If you're also concerned about functions, also run `command unset -f -- "$cmd"` before `type`.

Comment: @Gilles, you cannot redefine a builtin as a function in AT&T ksh88 though (at least not on Solaris).

Comment: You can on recent ksh93. `ksh -c 'echo ${.sh.version}; echo () { printf "wibble\n"; }; echo hello'` → `Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01`, `wibble`

Answer (score 0):

I fear you maybe wasted your time implementing that; `ksh93` supports the `builtin` command. E.g. with `ksh version 93t 2008-11-04`:

```
$ builtin
...creates list of all builtins

$ builtin jobs umask
...returns with exit code 0

$ builtin jobs time umask
...returns with exit code 1 and prints "builtin: time: not found"
```

Note also that the `builtin` command is a builtin, so the test you have in your code to exclude this specific builtin appears to be incorrect.

Comment: mksh doesn't support listing builtins. `builtin` with no argument does nothing.

Comment: @Gilles; I'm sure that there are even more shells ending in `*ksh` that do not support it. - If I talk about `ksh` I therefore mean the **original** AT&T `ksh`. - The OP mentioned the use of `ksh88`, a shell you nowadays find mostly just in commercial Unixes; so I assume he's also implying the original `ksh` in the two main variants (`ksh88` and `ksh93`).

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
#! /bin/sh

path_to_your_command=$(command -v your_command)

if [ "${path_to_your_command}" = 'your_command' ]; then
  echo 'your_command is a special builtin.'
else
  if [ -n "${path_to_your_command}" ]; then
    echo "your_command is a regular builtin, located at ${path_to_your_command}."
  else
    echo "your_command is not a builtin (and/or does not exist as it cannot be found in \$PATH)."
  fi
fi
```